# How to get both mapped source and destination member to create a custom mapping in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto

For example, let's say I need to map these classes:

```
public class Dto 
{
     public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string> { "orange", "apple" }
}

public class DomainObject
{
     public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

...and I'd like to configure a custom mapping using AutoMapper which returns the `DomainObject` after performing some operation where both `Dto` and `DomainObject`must be present, or at least I should be able to get both source `Items` and destination `Items`.

### Why I need this?

Because I'm mapping DTOs to change-tracked objects and I need to provide a custom approach to mapping collections in order to don't lose tracking information prior to the mapping operation.

For now, I've implemented the whole collection mapping in code using an extension method, but I would like to call this extension method as part of AutoMapper configuration in order to keep code as simple as possible and keep DRY too.

### Possible partial solution

I've found that AutoMapper has the following `IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>` method:

```
IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> AfterMap(Action<TSource, TDestination> afterFunction);
```

While this solves a 90% of my issue, there's still a problem. `AfterMap` doesn't give an instance of *current `IMapper`*. I'm not using static `Mapper` anymore, but I configure a custom factory on Castle Windsor for `IMapper`so I can inject it anywhere.

I also need an instance of current `IMapper`. I could do it resolving the `IMapper` *a la Service Locator anti-pattern*, but I would like to know if AutoMapper has  even another approach to do what already does `AfterMap` and maybe it can give current `IMapper` some way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not 100% satisfying solution using `AfterMap` during mapping configuration

This is my actual scenario:

```
mapperConfig.CreateMap<CustomerUpdateDto, Customer>()
                .ForMember(c => c.Locations, m => m.Ignore())
                .ForMember(c => c.Aliases, opts => opts.Ignore())
                .ForMember(c => c.Contacts, opts => opts.Ignore())
                .ForMember(c => c.Activities, opts => opts.Ignore())
                .AfterMap
                (
                    (dto, customer) =>
                    {
                        // AHHH! Dependency injection, please ;)
                        IMapper mapper = Container.Current.Resolve<IMapper>();

                        dto.Aliases.MapTo<ISet<CustomerAlias>, ISet<CustomerAlias>, CustomerAlias>(customer.Aliases, mapper);
                        dto.Activities.MapTo<ISet<Activity>, ISet<Activity>, Activity>(customer.Activities, mapper);
                        dto.Locations.MapTo<ISet<Location>, ISet<Location>, Location>(customer.Locations, mapper);
                    }
                )
                .ForAllMembers(options => options.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull));
```

`MapTo` is a custom extension method that generalizes a solution to avoid default AutoMapper behavior of creating new instances of entire collection instead of being able to map each collection item from the source to destination object:

```
public static class CollectionMappingExtensions
{
    public static void MapTo<TSource, TTarget, TItem>(this TSource source, TTarget target, IMapper mapper)
        where TSource : ICollection<TItem>
        where TTarget : ICollection<TItem>
    {
        foreach (TItem item in source)
        {
            TItem targetItem = target.SingleOrDefault(someItem => someItem.Equals(someItem));

            if (targetItem == null)
                target.Add(item);
            else
                mapper.Map(item, targetItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**BTW, it would be great if I could avoid getting the `IMapper` using a static *service locator* instead of a dependency injection.**